# Как изменить текст элемента <p>, внутри которого находится элемент <span>

Tags: javascript

Когда я изменяю текст внутри элемента `<p>`, содержимое `<span>` исчезает, и добавить его потом невозможно. Как изменить текст элемента `<p>` так, чтобы текст из `<span>` не исчез?

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick = function() {
  var p = document.getElementById("p");
  var span = document.getElementById("span")

  p.innerHTML = "asdf";

}
```

```html
<button id="button">click for me!</button>
<p id="p">123<span id="span">456</span></p>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Можно сделать, как предложил @Igor.

Минусы:

- Если на span есть какие-то события, или привязаны данные через dataset, то они потеряются.
- Тяжело будет менять, если у вас внутри несколько элементов. Например span, a, и еще что-либо.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick = function() {
  var p = document.getElementById("p");
  var span = document.getElementById("span")

  p.innerHTML = "asdf" + span.outerHTML;

}
span.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('span clicked'));
```

```css
#span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">click for me!</button>
<p id="p">123<span id="span">456</span></p>
```

Можно сделать,  обратиться к первому node(он у нас текстовый).

Минусы:

- Текстовый node может быть не первым. Их может быть несколько.

Плюсы:

- Span не пересоздается заново.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick = function() {
  var p = document.getElementById("p");
  var span = document.getElementById("span")

  p.firstChild.textContent = "asdf";

}
span.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('span clicked'));
```

```css
#span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">click for me!</button>
<p id="p">123<span id="span">456</span></p>
```

Самый лучший способ, на мой взгляд. Поменять разметку, текст вынести в отдельный элемент. Менять его, как вам нужно.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick = function() {
  var p = document.getElementById("p");
  var text = document.getElementById("text")

  text.innerText = "asdf";

}
span.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('span clicked'));
```

```css
#span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">click for me!</button>
<p id="p"><span id='text'>123</span><span id="span">456</span></p>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
p.innerHTML = "asdf" + span.outerHTML;
```